# How to generate a permutation list of lists in python

Tags: python, list, loops

I have the following data in a list of lists. This is a fuel bundle (with half symmetry) for a nuclear reactor and each number represents a fuel pin (with different enrichments).  The higher the number the more fuel. I'm trying to generate a large number of input files to run (I already have function that will enter my array into my input file and run it). 
***This is just a sample of what one array would look like***

```
20 
30 60
50 80 80 
60 80 80 80 
60 81 80 80 80 
60 80 80 00 00 80 
60 80 80 00 00 80 80 
50 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 
40 70 80 81 80 80 80 80 80
20 40 60 70 80 80 70 71 50 30
```

So I will be using rules to make lists. Like pins on the edges have to be low enrichment, pins that aren't divisible by 10 can't be on the edge or face adjacent to each other, or face adjacent to a 00. Since each spot has 90 options, I need to limit the total possibilities. This is why I wanted to generate a list of options for each location in the array, and then produce every possible array. I understand how to implement all of my rules,  I'm just confused about building all the possible array combinations.

How would I go about generating every possible combination for my array? Or if there is a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do. My Python experience is only about two weeks worth.

Comment: I don't see what your triangle of numbers is supposed to be. And where did [10, 20, 30] come from? I don't see that as any row in your list.

Comment: Can you give a more explicit example of what you are trying to accomplish? Your wording is unclear.

Comment: I think the way we are all currently picturing it is `list[0][0]` would access `20`. Does pin `20` correlate to `[10, 20, 30]`?

Comment: So I will be using rules to make lists.  Like pins on the edges have to be low enrichment, pins that aren't divisible by 10 can't be on the edge or face adjacent to each other, or face adjacent to a 00.  Since each spot has 90 options, I need to limit the total possibilities.  This is why I wanted to generate a list of options for each location in the array

Comment: Your wording is nuclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you, it's relatively straightforward using tools in the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html) module.  Something like

```
from itertools import product, chain

def choose_from_2d_lol(lol):
    flattened_options = list(chain.from_iterable(lol))
    for p in product(*flattened_options):
        p_iter = iter(p)
        new_list = [[next(p_iter) for elem in row] for row in lol]
        yield new_list
```

will iterate over all possibilities:

```
>>> xx = [[[10,20,30]],[[44], [55,66]]]
>>> for chosen in choose_from_2d_lol(xx):
...     print(chosen)
...     
[[10], [44, 55]]
[[10], [44, 66]]
[[20], [44, 55]]
[[20], [44, 66]]
[[30], [44, 55]]
[[30], [44, 66]]
```

Note, though, that going through every possibility this way could very well be completely infeasible as the number of possibilities will grow very rapidly.

Comment: Sorry would you be able to explain what exactly you're doing here

`flattened_options = list(chain.from_iterable(lol))`

Comment: @Greg: add `print(flattened_options)` after that line to see. Basically it takes the list-of-lists `lol` and turns it into a flat list, so here it turns `xx` into `[[10, 20, 30], [44], [55, 66]]`.

Comment: Does `from_iterable` have a function or is it just a generic name you used?  I can see this does what I want, I am just trying to understand it so it's not just a black box that does what I want.

Comment: If you click on the link to the `itertools` documentation you can scroll down and click on `chain.from_iterable`.

Comment: Okay thanks, OOP is still very new to me. Is `from_iterable` an instance of `chain` that you made?

Comment: No, you can think of `chain.from_iterable` as like a function.  `chain.from_iterable(lol)` produces an `itertools.chain` instance, which we then call `list` on to iterate over and produce a list.